# Hacer validaciones en un DataGridViewComboBoxColumn - C# | NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, windows-forms

¡Hola Gente! Tengo un DataGridView y en modo diseño le puse un DataGridViewComboBoxColumn, cargo los elementos en el Load() del formulario.

Es una orden de compra lo que estoy haciendo de modo que al cliquear el botón "Guardar", si el usuario no seleccionó nada en el Combo solo para probar que pasa, quiero arrojar un mensaje que diga que debe de seleccionar al menos un producto pero no sé cómo hacer la verificación por si la primera fila del ComboBoxColumn está sin seleccionar elemento.

Aparentemente en un ComboBoxColumn las propiedades **Selected Index** o **Selected Item** no existen, a diferencia de los ComboBox tradicionales. al menos yo no las encuentro si hago **ProductColum.Items. ??**

Quisiera saber, ¿Cómo hago para mostrar un mensaje si el usuario no ha seleccionado ningún elemento alojado en el ComboBoxColumn? Intenté esto:

```
  if (ProductsDataGrid.Rows.Count == 1)
  {
     MessageBox.Show("DEBES DE SELECCIONAR AL MENOS UN PRODUCTO.");
     return;
  }
  else
  {
     MessageBox.Show("Guardado exitosamente.");
  }
```

y funciona pero lo que está verificando es si el ComboBoxColumn tiene una fila, ya que al ejecutar el Form, la barra desplegable con el nombre de los productos las cuenta como una fila; de modo que supongo que a futuro esa sentencia me podría generar problemas con una base de datos con muchos más de los 6 productos que estoy probando.

Adicionalmente, he probado capturando el valor de la fila seleccionada:
**ProductsDataGrid.Rows[currentrow].Cells[0].Value.ToString();**

**Cells[0]** porque en la columna 0 se aloja el ComboBox.

Pero me arroja una *NullReferenceException*

¡Gracias de antemano!

Comment: de la documentacion de comboboxcollumn: "Unlike the ComboBox control, the DataGridViewComboBoxCell does not have SelectedIndex and SelectedValue properties. Instead, selecting a value from a drop-down list sets the cell Value property." o sea.. que la celda tiene o no valor, dependiendo de si hay seleccion o no... se entiende?

Comment: entiendo el concepto, eso no lo sabía pero sigo con la pregunta activa con hacer la verificación, podría deshabilitar el botón "Guardar" pero con qué requisitos lo activo de nuevo?

Comment: eso no esta por ningun lado en tu pregunta... sabiendo esto, no basta con verificar si cambio el valor de esa celda, y la fila quedo valida? igual las grillas tienen tambien eventos de validacion...

Comment: lo del botón si lo mencioné solo que no estaba pensando en desactivarlo, ya que todo mi código de inserción de datos y esa validación están el el evento click del botón.

Comment: Entonces vamos de vuelta.. tu pregunta con mi comentario queda completa? lo pongo como respuesta? y lo otro, no esta en la pregunta... asi que habria que hacer una nueva pregunta...

Comment: ya lo arreglé, no me sirvió nada de lo que me dijiste en el código pero si como conocimiento. **DataGridView.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value == null**

Comment: y eso no es justamente lo que te dije en el primer comentario?